# rdlc textbox overlapping each other when text is longer than textbox width

Tags: c#-4.0, wpf-controls, rdlc

In my rdlc , I have several textbox alight from top to bottom as follow :

```
textbox1
textbox2
textbox3
```

Whenever the text inside the text box is longer than the given width, it will overlap the textbox below it , What i need is not overlapping it, but to push down the text box .

I have reference [http://forums.asp.net/t/1590478.aspx?textbox+with+too+long+text+overlapps+textbox+beneath](http://forums.asp.net/t/1590478.aspx?textbox%20with%20too%20long%20text%20overlapps%20textbox%20beneath) , but the solution is not working for me.

My question is how should whenever my text is longer than given width of the textbox, how do I prevent it overlapping the textbox below it , or how to push the text box below it ?

Comment: I didn't encounter this problem, so just thinking out loud, maybe you can try to place each textbox in separate container? placing them into three-rows of a table maybe another option.